# What is the distribution of $\frac{\sum(x_t-a_t)^2}{\sum(x_t-b_t)^2}$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Let $x_t, t \geq 1$, be a sequence of independent random variables, $x_t \sim N(a_t,\sigma^2), t \geq 1$, $a_t, b_t \in \mathbb{R}$. What is the distribution of $S_n$, where:
$$S_n=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^n(x_t-a_t)^2}{\sum_{t=1}^n(x_t-b_t)^2}$$

Comment: It looks like a generalization of the $F$ distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Definition)

Comment: @JeanMarie This does not look like it at all, because the numerator and denominator are not independent with each other.

Comment: I overlooked it. Sorry. A remark: as one can divide the numerator and the denominator by $\sigma^2$, you could simplify the expression of $S_n$ as $S_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-c_k)^2} $ with $x_k \sim N(0,1)$. I am right, this time ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: You are right. What can I do next ? As I know, for normal distribution the statistics $S_n^2$ and $\overline{X}$ are independent. But I think it cannot help in this case.

Comment: In my opinion, one can try to work on the inverse of $S_n$: by expanding the new numerator (old denominator), you get $1-2\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\dfrac{x_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2 \dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2}$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. I will think of this more.